# Configure preferred host on which to run?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-cluster

We have set up a virtual Microsoft clustered environment and I want to set one virtual machine to run on each physical server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set an Anti-Affinity rule in the cluster's DRS settings.